# Run Tensorflow in Qubole

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark, qubole

I am trying to train LSTM using Spark python Notebook in Qubole. When I try to fit model, I received below error.

> I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX

Why this error occur and how can I overcome this?

Comment: It seems like not an error but a warning

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, but a warning. The pre-built tensorflow binaries are not compiled with various CPU instruction extensions because not everyone has them. When TensorFlow is started, it checks which extensions are available on your machine and which ones the binary was compiled with. If your machine has some extensions that the binary was not compiled with, it lets you know this. If you do a lot of CPU computation and care about ultimate performance, you can build tensorflow yourself with extensions present on your machine.